# How to pass data between multiple Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-listfragment, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

In my main Activity, I have a DialogFragment that contains a FragmentTabHost. I have two tabs, one that is a DialogFragment and one that is a ListFragment. When either the 'OK' button is pressed in the inner DialogFragment or when an element in the ListFragment is pressed, I want to pass two Strings (that are entered in two TextView's in the inner DialogFragment and are displayed in each element in the ListFragment) back to the Activity, but I am unsure of how to do this with multiple levels of Fragments.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic.

You can achieve with two approaches.

1. Use callback.

Create interface and class to pass the data through child Fragment to Activity. You don't need to modify bridged `TabHostFragment` as Fragment always rely on its mother Context (Activity) no matter how many fragments wrap the fragment.

```
public class TwoStrings {
    public TwoStrings(String one, String two){
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }
    public String one;
    public String two;
}
```

First, declare interface.

```
public interface DataPassListener {
    void dataPassed(TwoStrings data);
}
```

And, implement interface in Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DataPassListener {
    @Override
    public void dataPassed(TwoStrings data) {
        // do something with data.
        Log.d("string one", data.one);
        Log.d("string two", data.two);
    }
}
```

Finally, let child Fragment acknowlege that mother Activity has the callback listener.

```
public class DialogFragment1 extends DialogFragment {
    DataPassListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceOf DataPassListener)
            listener = (DataPassListener) activity;
    }

    public void setDataPassListener(DataPassListener listener){
        listener = ((DataPassListener) listener);
    }    

    public void doSomeThing(){
        if(listener != null) // important to prevent NullPointerException
            listener.dataPassed("a", "b");
    }
}
```

2. Use EventBus.

I prefer to use [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) in order to publish and subscribe data.

To subscribe event for listening in Activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onUpdateTwoStrings(TwoStrings event) {
        // do something with data.
        Log.d("string one", data.one);
        Log.d("string two", data.two);
    }
}
```

And, publish event in anywhere in Fragment.

```
bus.post(new TwoStrings("a", "b"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [setTargetFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int)) and [getTargetFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment()) methods. You could connect fragments with each other through it without any additional callbacks and libs.