# Should I use fragments or activities for my app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I know this question probably gets asked a lot, but I wanted to get an answer specifically for the kind of app I'm building. I'm creating an Android app, which is basically a recipe search app which allows the user to choose ingredients, food categories, and preparation time and the app would find recipes that fit the user's search.

There are individual "pages" for ingredients, categories, and time, and I have created an activity for each. The user picks ingredients first, then when they click Next, the category activity is started, and then once again when they click Next, the preparation time activity comes up. Then when they click Search, I have another activity for results, and when the user clicks one of the recipes in the results, another activity for displaying the recipe starts.

So I have the following activities, where each activity starts the next in the following order:

- IngredientActivity
- CategoryActivity
- TimeActivity
- ResultActivity
- RecipeActivity

I did some reading and found out that I should have probably used fragments. My plan is to change my app so it would have a tabbed activity with three tabs for ingredients, categories and time, with a Search button at the bottom which is displayed in all three fragments, which allows the user to easily switch between tabs and search from whichever tab they're currently viewing. As for results and displaying recipes, I'm thinking to leave their respective activities as they are. The Search button starts the ResultActivity, and clicking on an individual search result starts the RecipeActivity and displays the recipe the user clicked on.

In addition, I'm planning to add a "search by recipe title" function. The user would be able to switch between those two search modes using a menu button in the action bar. I'm assuming each search mode would have to have a separate activity, so that's what I'm planning to do.

Is my idea the correct way to do it? Or should I have just one activity for the entire app and do the rest exclusively with fragments?

Comment: IMO, i will use fragments. All of your so called activities will be inflated under a main activity, perhaps say `MainActivity`. Then by using a ViewPager, you can allow your user to navigate back and forward the fragments. To navigate forward, simply have a FAB, and have a "Up" button handled in your `MainActivity`

Comment: @ZhiKai So I should have just one activity and navigate the fragments with an up button within the FAB? I'm not sure I fully get what you mean...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me, all decisions about *Activity or Fragment* are related to (1) UX (2) Manageability (3) Communication cost across components, etc.

Let me introduce some decisions by examples.

1. Is the screen required to launch from outside (Share intent)?

   - `Activity` is better as it can be opened directly from what AndroidManifest gives.
2. Does the screen require page-by-page views (recipe pages)?

   - `Fragment` is better as Fragment+ViewPager give flexible paging fuctionality. Moreover, some Android devices or theme editors override Activity opening effects so page-turning animation does not run as expected if we implements it in Activity-by-Activity manner.
3. Does the screen execute Camera or Photo intent with `StartActivity`?

   - `Activity` is better as `OnActivityResult` is hard to manage inner fragments when the app restores back from the Camera apps. For this reason, "writing a post" screen could be a good example to be a single Activity.
4. Does the screen have to run regardless of screen on/off (Timers)?

   - `Activity` is better as it can show up faster and lighter without [Activity-Fragment dancing](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2014/08/complete-android-activity-and-fragment-lifecycle/).
5. Does the screen have a kind of master-detail hierarchy?

   - `Fragment` is better because we could prepare tablet layout.
6. Does the screen consume memory a lot?

   - `Activity` is better because we can focus on the activity solely not inner fragments memory usage.
7. Does the screen has nested fragments more than 3-depth?

   - `Fragment`, reluctantly. Communication between fragment is unstable and Activity-Fragment bridging/dancing is always headache [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30554102/361100) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30772541/361100). We can make complexity lower but Activity-inside-Fragment-inside-ViewPager-inside-fragment-... is hard to acheive manageability.

Using multiple `Fragment` with single `Activity` is recommended by professional Android developers but we could decide to create more Activities for easier management and faster understanding.

In your case, I would like to implement components as below.

- MainActivity with Fragments: Ingredients, Categories, Recipe.
- ResultActivity with Fragments: Search and its Results are a kind of master-detail view.
- TimerActivity: It should be good to run in single Activity.
- RecipeActivity: If each recipe has its own id and can be shared as permalink, your app could open directly the recipe page by RecipeActivity. And, it could be better to show recipe even if your app is restored from turned-off or switched back from another app situation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. TimeActivity is not a timer though, it's just a page which let's the user choose the maximum preparation time required for recipes, so the search results could be filtered according to the time the user chooses. Also, why do you think the "page" that displays recipes should not get a separate activity?

Comment: @user3501779 // recipe is fine to create to Activity. I just decided 'choose fragment when it is not so complex'.

Comment: @user3501779 // I edited to reflect your opinion. As you know, there's no _right_ answer, just _acceptable in case_ exists.